# msg.sender is not showing corect value

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethereumjs

I am facing a strange issue. Please read the below case craefully and assit me to geth this issue resolved.

I have ERC20Token created by Zeppling templates.

[Please ignore syntaxes, I am just trying to expling my use case:]

Here is a protoype of token code:

Contract 1:

```
SampleErc20Token

{
    constructor(_tokenHolderAccess)
    {
        balances[_tokenHolderAccess]=1000000;       
    }

    transfer(to, amount)
    {
        balance[msg.sender]///// Here is the issue.
    }
}

DummyContarcts(_erc20TokenObject)

{
    DoSomething
{
    _erc20TokenObject.transfer(newTokenHolderadress, 10000);

}


}
```

In Truffile test case I am deploying
SampleErc20Token and DummyContarcts from accounts[0]

In SampleErc20Token Constructor I am passing the address of DummyContarcts .

Now with the instance of DummyContarcts I call method DoSomething, which internally calls _erc20TokenObject.transfer. In this case msg.sender in transfer methid should be DummyContarcts onject.
But its picking some random address. Can any one help me to solve this puzzle please.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The concept looks right, so it is likely an implementation detail

Comment: Sure. Let me see what best I can do in MCVE

Comment: contract MyToken is StandardToken {
  constructor (address addr) public {
   totalSupply_= 10000;    balances[addr] = totalSupply_;  }
 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);}}

contract D {
 function doTransfer(address newTokenHolder,MyToken erc20Toekn) external wasNotReplaced adminsVotingApproved {
    erc20Toekn.transfer(newTokenHolder, 20); 
  }

 }

===============================

Now if I call D.doTransfer then erc20Toekn.transfer is called and there balances[msg.sender] is different than D address.

Comment: With some small modifications, your code works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/RaghavSood/a1c27edaf189576174f8718085a13697. It sounds like something in the way you are doing your truffle tests is incorrect, or your actual code does something different.